# Need Help in updating 10 million rows

Tags: oracle

I need to update the table A with only 2 columns from the table B.
(Tables A,B has only 2 columns in common - col1a,co11b ::col2a,col2b

Sample script:  I wanted to update all col1a values with col1b where col2a=col2b

```
UPDATE a
   SET col1a = (SELECT col1b
                  FROM b
                 WHERE a.col2a = b.col2b)
```

As the data is huge,I want to commit rows at regular intervals (say 5000 records).
Can you please suggest .

Comment: You can use the LIMIT keyword or even do your own interval using the "id" field if you got one (1 < id < 5000 [...])

Comment: 10 million rows is not a lot of data these days.  Why do you want to commit in intervals?  That will, at a minimum, make things slower.  And it will require quite a bit more code.  And it will generate more `UNDO` and `REDO`.  Are you really sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: I have to commit at regular intervals. But not sure on the no.of row to commit. 
It is an input parameter to the procedure.
I have to commit based on the input parameter.

Comment: Why do you *have* to commit at regular intervals? That doesn't make sense. Just commit at the end and everything is fine.

Comment: As we are updating sensitive data.
We just wanted to make sure it commits at regular intervals
(Customer requirement)

Comment: Can you give us a little more information here about the tables. Ae the columns col2a and col2b primary keys of the respective tables? How big are the tables? Are they both 10 million rows or just one of them??

Comment: Also, I'd have to disagree that committing at regular intervals is a "customer requirement". It just shouldn't be necessary. If your database can handle 10 million rows in a table, it can handle updating all those rows without committing every few thousand rows.

Answer (score 4):

Since the query you have shown in the question contains a subquery, this is doing a lookup on table b for every row that is being updated. This can be slow, and update is a slow enough operation anyway.

Depending on the design of your tables, I would try to "UPDATE a view" or MERGE. The ability to the UPDATE depends on there being a "key-preserved join". If you don't have that, the UPDATE won't work. It's a little hard to give a proper answer without some sort of DDL for the tables.

```
UPDATE (
  select col1a, col1b, col2a, col2b
  from 
    a join b on (a.col2a = b.col2b)
)
set col1a = col1b;
```

If the UPDATE doesn't work, you can then try the MERGE. This should work in more circumstances than the update.

```
merge into a
using b on (a.col2a = b.col2b)
when matched then update set a.col1a = b.col1b
```

The advantage of both of these statements is that they work on the whole set of data rather than updating one row at a time. It can be difficult to get an update to perform well.

It might also be worth removing any indexes on the `col1a` column if there are any.

Comment: The only caveat I'd mention about the `MERGE` statement is that it requires a `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clause with an `INSERT` statement, so it may not be the best choice in this case.  I do, however, agree that removing indexes on `col1a` would be good, as would possibly removing any constraints, as that can speed updates.

Comment: @MauriceReeves I thought the `INSERT` clause was required too but it seemed to be optional when I looked at the 10r2 documentation and SQL Fiddle didn't complain when I left it out.

Comment: Weird.  When I've built `MERGE` statements on Oracle 11g I got complaints about missing clauses, etc when I didn't include the `INSERT`.  Wondering if 10r2 was more forgiving....

Comment: @MauriceReeves The `WHEN NOT MATCHED` hasn't been required since [9i](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/statements_915a.htm#2080942).  One big advantage of `MERGE` over `UPDATE` is that only `MERGE` can use a hash join.

Comment: @JohnEarles - That's odd.  I wonder why I had compilation issues.  I need to go back and look at that again.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all. I got the solution.
 I was looking for the the solution like below

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE xxwv_cc_token_conversion (
   p_source_table   IN   VARCHAR2,
   p_dest_table     IN   VARCHAR2,
   p_column_name    IN   VARCHAR2,
   p_commit_row     IN   NUMBER
)
IS
   TYPE cv_typ IS REF CURSOR;

   t_cur    cv_typ;

   TYPE token_num IS TABLE OF xxwv_ap_token_test2.token_number%TYPE
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   TYPE row_num IS TABLE OF xxwv_ap_token_test2.row_id%TYPE
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   ex_sql   VARCHAR2 (2000);
   t_num    token_num;
   r_num    token_num;
BEGIN
   OPEN t_cur FOR    ' SELECT token_number, row_id FROM '
                  || p_source_table
                  || ' WHERE ROWNUM < 100';

   LOOP
      FETCH t_cur
      BULK COLLECT INTO t_num, r_num LIMIT p_commit_row;

      ex_sql :=
            'UPDATE '
         || p_dest_table
         || ' SET '
         || p_column_name
         || ' = :1,token_flag = ''Y''  WHERE row_id =  :2';
      FORALL i IN 1 .. t_num.COUNT
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ex_sql
                     USING t_num (i), r_num (i);
      COMMIT;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('commit finished');
      EXIT WHEN t_cur%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE t_cur;

   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Error occured while updating' || SQLERRM);
END xxwv_cc_token_conversion;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted and if possible in your environment, you can

```
 create table newtable as select .... from oldtable
```

which will create a new table.

Then recreate indexes, rename the two tables and recreate constraints.

Comment: This is make sense, but still creating and deleting afterwards :D +1